# How to provide kotlin class for eclipse run configurations?

Tags: java, eclipse, kotlin

I am trying to create a Run configuration for a kotlin class. I've got the same configuration in Java, and now try to adopt it to kotlin. I need to provide program arguments as "run this.package.this.class.name other.options", for example, "run test.java.MyMainClass blahblahblah" but now my main class has got an extension .kt, I tried both "run test.java.MyMainClass.kt" and "run test.java.MyMainClass.KClass" but compiler still says "ClassNotFoundException".

Comment: How about `test.java.MyMainClassKt` ?

Answer (score -1):

As @miensol says in a comment, kotlinc adds a 'Kt' suffix to the class name so you would need to use

`run test.java.MyMainClassKt`